# Работа со словарями python

Tags: python

Как удалить значение "dagger" из ключа "backpack"

```
d = {'gold': 500, 'pouch': ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'],
 'backpack':['xylophone', 'dagger', 'bedroll', 'bread loaf']}

d['pocket'] = ['seashell', 'strange berry', 'lint']
print(d)

backpack_s = sorted(d['backpack'])
print(backpack_s)

d_keys = d.keys()
d_values = d.values()
print(d_keys)
print(d_values)
```

Answer (score 4):

Например так:

```
d['backpack'].remove('dagger')
```

Вообще это основы работы со списками и словарями. Почитайте какой-нибудь таториал.

P.S. Через `del` тоже можно было бы, но гораздо более муторно:

```
del d['backpack'][d['backpack'].index('dagger')]
```

Comment: Спасибо, забыл про ремув совсем, пытался удалить функцией del )

Comment: @darkdarklord Через `del` тоже можно, конечно, только обратиться к нужному элементу списка для этого не так просто )  Я добавил код с `del` для общего развития

Comment: @darkdarklord, если ответ вам помог, вы можете [принять лучший, по вашему мнению, ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) и [проголосовать за все понравившиеся ответы](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814)